# Values can't be taken by a real function

Tags: functions, contest-math

> Which of the following values can't be taken by the real function
> $f(x)=\frac{x}{x^2+4x+16}$ ?
>
> 1. $\frac{1}{12}$
> 2. $\frac{-1}{4}$
> 3. $\frac{1}{4}$
> 4. $\frac{-1}{12}$

My solution approach :-
$f(x)=\frac{x}{x^2+4x+16}$
$\Rightarrow f(x)=\frac{x}{(x+2)^2 +12}$

As the denominator can never be $0$ no matter what value of $x$ you put into the equation, doesn't this mean that $x$ can take all the values in the given function? Is the given question wrong? Please help !!!

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: $x$ can take all values, but the question is asking what values $f(x)$ can/cannot take.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, and a counter-example can be $g(x)=\frac {1}{x^2+1}$. The denominator is never $0$, but, $g(x)=\frac {-1}{2}$ has no solutions.
In order to solve the problem you should try to find out the range.
Let $$y=\frac{x}{x^2+4x+16}$$
So $$yx^2+(4y-1)x+16y=0$$
Since this quadratic equation has real roots if $y$ is in range, we get:
$$D\geq 0$$
$$(4y-1)^2-4y(16y)\geq 0$$
$$(-4y-1)(12y-1)\geq 0$$
$$(4y+1)(12y-1)\leq 0$$
Thus, $y \in [-\frac 14, \frac {1}{12}]$ is the range of $f(x)$.
Hence only option (3) is outside the range.

Comment: Oh...okk...so we need to find the values for $y$. Now I got it...thanks for all the help..
I misread the problem then...

Comment: Yes, domain was unimportant here. The question was about range.